# Undefined Mixin 'if-rem' using Susy CSS

Tags: susy-compass

When trying to compile a Susy/Compass document I'm getting `Undefined mixin 'if-rem'`.

It's this line that's causing it:

[Line 35 of _grid.scss](https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/master/sass/susy/_grid.scss#L35)

I'm using:

- SASS 3.2.12
- Compass 0.12.2
- Susy 1.0.9

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says you should define `if-rem` mixin before include it. So you have two options:

- Import _unit.scss into your style. This is the susy partial that contains the `if-rem` mixin declaration

  ```
  // Imports

  @import "compass/utilities/general/clearfix";
  @import "compass/css3/box-sizing";
  // add _unit.scss path here, or elsewhere before the @include
  @import "susy/units";
  ```
- Include the `if-rem` mixin directly into your code, you should also include the variable or `if-rem` mixin will return an error:

  ```
  // Whether to output fallback values in px when outputting rems.
  $rem-with-px-fallback: true !default;

  // Here is the`if-rem` mixin declaration
  @mixin if-rem($property, $values, $use-px-fallback: $rem-with-px-fallback) {
    $has-rem: false;
    @each $value in $values { $has-rem: if(unit($value) == 'rem', true, $has-rem); }
    @if $has-rem { @include rem($property, $values, $use-px-fallback); }
    @else { #{$property}: $values; }
  }
  ```